# Submitting Comments from Control Panel

Tags: control-panel, comments

Hello ExpressionEngine gurus!

Could someone please show me how to add comments to an ExpressionEngine 2-based site from its control panel, being logged in as a Super Admin (as opposed to entering comments using the front end comment submission form)?

Would be grateful for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't add comments from the control panel, to the best of my knowledge. You can manage comments— delete or edit, but I believe creating comments is purely a front end experience, unless you're talking about commenting code in the templates.

Comments are a 'user-based experience' item. Managing comments is a 'super-admin' experience. This can be done via the edit entries view or from clicking the recent comments link on the home screen of the control panel.

Comment: Thanks, nonprofit_tech! That's what I thought, too, but I decided to enquire, just in case.

Comment: Would be a very nice feature though. I just happened to need this function as well. 2018 EE5.